# How to load a mesh from the .X-format in DirectX10 via SlimDX?

Tags: c#, 3d-meshes, directx, directx10, slimdx

As of DirectX10, the usual functions to load a mesh in the .X-format are marked as deprecated and they are DX9 functions anyway. How can I load a mesh from the .X-format into an `ID3DX10Mesh` object using the SlimDX wrapper?

Answer (score 1):

There's a "SimpleModel10" sample in the samples distribution for SlimDX -- it is essentially the same code as in the [ScapeCode](http://www.scapecode.com/?p=127) post. In fact, it was written by the same developer.